# Djangoで作ったアプリをherokuへデプロイ後、アプリが表示されません。

Tags: django, heroku

Djangoで作ったアプリをherokuへデプロイ後、アプリが表示されません。
デプロイ後、アプリのURLを開くと
以下のようなエラーがでました。

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail
```

ログをチャックする必要があるとのことで確認したところ
以下のようなエラーが確認できたのですが、検索しても明確な答えが見つかりませんでした。
このエラー（at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"）は、どのような原因で起こりえるのでしょうか？
また、解決方法もあればアドバイスいただけますと助かります。

抜粋

```
2020-12-11T07:28:47.775779+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hogehoge.herokuapp.com request_id=ea446ace-d220-4db4-bab8-4466266d8650 fwd="69.118.84.101" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-11T07:28:47.909678+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hogehoge.herokuapp.com request_id=c5b7a954-6d34-4a6e-87e1-2428df78ae29 fwd="69.118.84.101" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2020-12-11T07:04:39.534550+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hogehoge.herokuapp.com request_id=58dbe69a-0704-44f8-aefb-ff777769a7a8 fwd="69.118.84.101" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-11T07:04:40.143720+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hogehoge.herokuapp.com request_id=be70bdb3-5501-4f94-837f-785c694ef87e fwd="69.118.84.101" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

ご質問のエラーコードはアプリがクラッシュしたか起動のタイムアウトだと思います。
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed

Herokuでアプリを実行するには、

- requirements.txt
- Procfile
- runtime.txt

以上の3つが必要です。すべて、リポジトリのルートに配置します。

requirements.txt

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

requirements.txtは、上記のコマンドをリポジトリのルートで実行してください。

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn myproject.wsgi
```

runtime.txt

```
python-3.9.0
```

Procfileとruntime.txtはファイルを作成して書いて下さい。
Procfileの`myproject.wsgi`はプロジェクト名に変更してください。
djangoの開発用のサーバーは運用環境では適さないため、gunicornを使用しています。
requirements.txtを作成前に下記のコマンドを実行してください。

```
pip install gunicorn
```

参考リンク
https://devcenter.heroku.com/ja/articles/django-app-configuration
https://devcenter.heroku.com/ja/articles/deploying-python
https://devcenter.heroku.com/ja/articles/getting-started-with-python